# How to use Create React App using Yarn 2?

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

In yarn v1 we initialize create react app using `yarn create react-app my-app`. How to initialize the same in yan v2.

The above command gives the error

```
Usage Error: No project found in <<directory>>

$ yarn run <scriptName> ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yarn dlx create-react-app my-app`. It will work.
There are a lot of changes came with the yarn version2 update.
check this also for additional info: https://dev.to/arcanis/introducing-yarn-2-4eh1

Comment: This doesn't work particularly well within a yarn 2 monorepo - it will also add the .pnp.cjs file, .yarn folder into the package folder, rather than it being at the root.

Answer (score 6):

Check your yarn version:

```
yarn --version
```

If it's below 1.22 you may need to upgrade it to use yarn 2:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

You can then create your app:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn set version berry
yarn
yarn start
```

This should have your react app up and running using yarn 2. You may want to remove the node_modules folder:

```
rm -R node_modules
```

Also, you need the next line on  `.yarnrc.yml`

```
nodeLinker: "node-modules"
```

Comment: is `yarn create react-app` a typo? It shouldn't have a space?

Comment: no it's not a typo https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create/

Comment: Not sure why you rm -R node_modules here and then set the nodeLinker to node-modules in the yarnrc?  Seems like whatever that is designed to accomplish, it would require an additional run of yarn install after that which would recreate the node_modules because you've moved away from nodeLinker: "pnp" ?

Comment: You should just use `npm install -g yarn@berry`, since the latest tag is Yarn Classic (1.x)